# Coldfusion: download PDF

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, download

I have a URL that opens a PDF:

```
<cfoutput>http://myUrl.cfm?params=#many#<cfoutput>
```

I would like to enable my users to download that PDF instead of having it open in the browser. I've been trying the following, and it isn't working:

```
<cfoutput>    
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="http://myUrl.cfm?params=#many#"/> 
<cfheader name="content-diposition" value="attachment; filename='http://myUrl.cfm?params=#many#'">
<cflocation url= "http://myUrl.cfm?params=#many#"/>
</cfoutput>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`<cfheader>` before `<cfcontent>`

you don't need `<cflocation>`.

http://tutorial217.easycfm.com/

Comment: He also doesn't need the cfoutput block.

Comment: Also 1) The cfcontent "file" value should be an absolute path (ie c:\pathTo\file.pdf". 2) The cfheader "filename" should be a _name_ like "someFile.pdf", not a URL.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="unknown">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=FileName.jpg">
<cfcontent type="Application/Unknown" file="/http//downloads/FileName.jpg" deletefile="No">
```